# Override project settings from an app?

Tags: python, django

How could I override or change the project's settings from an app? For example, I have a context processor function in my app, and I want to include it into a `context_processors` option of the `TEMPLATE` setting. How could I do that without changing project's `settings.py` file directly?
In the documentation i found, that they cannot be changed at runtime:

> You shouldn’t alter settings in your applications at runtime. For
>   example, don’t do this in a view:
>
> `from django.conf import settings`
>   `settings.DEBUG = True   # Don't do this!`
>
> The only place you should assign to settings is in a settings file.

So is it possible at all?

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here. An app is just a collection of models and views. Are you saying you want the context processor to only be invoked when a template is rendered from one of the views in the app, and not from any other views? If so, why?

Comment: I just want to add context processor to settings. So that user won't need to do that, if he uses my app in a project.